# Why cannot I poll() on a multiprocessing.Connection object on Windows?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Using [multiprocessing.Pipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe) I create two [multiprocessing.Connection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#Connection) objects, for one of which I read the file descriptor/handle through `Conection.fileno()` and then pass it as a command line argument to another process. I believe this is similar to how multiprocessing spawns child-processes.

In a child process, I'm creating a [multiprocessing.Connection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#Connection) object by reading the handle from a command line argument, and then communicate between two processes.

This works well on my mac but for some reason calling the `Connection.poll` method on windows results in the following error:

> IOError: [Errno 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

What is the cause of the difference? Why there's no mention of that in `poll`s documentation?

A simple code example could be something like:

In father.py:

```
c1, c2 = multiprocessing.Pipe()
subprocess.Popen(['child.py', str(c1.fileno())])
```

In child.py:

```
c1 = multiprocessing.Connection(int(sys.argv[1]))
c1.poll(1)
```

For additional details, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51550131/interprocess-communication-with-a-modified-python-interpreter) question and answer of mine describe what I'm trying to achieve and how I ended up doing that.

Comment: What kind of connection is it? Named pipe? Socket? Can you provide a code example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @jbch Edited to include more info and added a dummy code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was not specific to `poll`, but with all `Connection` methods interacting with the underlaying handle (`recv`, `send`).

Because `multiprocessing.Pipe` creates a *named pipe* in windows, combined with how pipe handle inheritance works in python2 (which once identified as the root cause shown to be [discussed](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2008-December/509460.html) [pretty](https://bugs.python.org/issue3905) [heavily](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0446/)) passing on an handle seems to be very difficult if not impossible.

Going over multiprocessing's documentation again, I noticed the [`Listener` and `Client` interfaces](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-listeners-clients) which worked well for me, passing along whatever was in the  `Listener.address` attribute to `Client`s constructor.